# Guzzle : Bad query string formatting

Tags: php, guzzle, guzzle6

With this code,

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri'=> 'http://example.com']);
try{
     $data = ['params1'=>'value1', 'params2'=> 'value2'];
     $res = $client->request('GET', '/', ['query'=> $data]);
}catch(\GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException $e)
{
      echo $e->getRequest()->getUri();
}
```

This is output :

```
 http://example.com/?params1=value1params2=value2
```

You can see absence of ampersand in the string queries of request uri !

How resolve this problem ?

Comment: are you sure that you're using guzzle 6?

Comment: Yes ! Guzzle v6.0-dev

Comment: upgrade your guzzle's version to a stable version. your code is good, and it will works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri'=> 'http://example.com']);
try{
    $data = ['params1'=>'value1', 'params2'=> 'value2'];
    $res = $client->request('GET', '/', ['query'=> http_build_query($data)]);
}catch(\GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException $e)
{
    echo $e->getRequest()->getUri();
}
```

Comment: Than you a lot ! it works ! using the `http_build_query` native function

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug fixed in the [6.0.1 version](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/commit/6f3db1618ef286e993db255b7a734f5cadb1f1a8). Please, use a stable version of guzzle, and your code will works.